# Installing npm in ununtu 14.04 LTS

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

Hi I am trying to install `npm` in **[Ubuntu 14.04 LTS](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/)**.

What I have done is-

```
sudo apt-get install npm
```

And I am getting-

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 npm : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-abbrev (>= 1.0.4) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-ansi but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-archy but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-block-stream but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-fstream (>= 0.1.22) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-fstream-ignore but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-github-url-from-git but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-glob (>= 3.1.21) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-graceful-fs (>= 2.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-inherits but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-ini (>= 1.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-lockfile but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-lru-cache (>= 2.3.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-minimatch (>= 0.2.11) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-mkdirp (>= 0.3.3) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-gyp (>= 0.10.9) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-nopt (>= 2.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-npmlog but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-once but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-osenv but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-read but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-read-package-json (>= 1.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-request (>= 2.25.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-retry but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-rimraf (>= 2.2.2) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-semver (>= 2.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-sha but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-slide but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-tar (>= 0.1.18) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-which but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Can anyone please help?

### Update-

What I have tried is-

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

And

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And then installing, but not solved.

**Again-**

Trying to remove all listed packages like this-

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge <package>
```

And getting this-

[image]

Comment: Use NVM (Node Version Manager)

Comment: not an option, because all the codes are using npm, not nvm, so if I do that it may be a catastrophic effect.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps you should follow.

- To resolve conflicts `sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep hold`
- Remove (`sudo apt-get remove --purge <package>`) all the packages that above command lists.

Now install `Node` the right way:

- `curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_5.x | sudo -E bash -`
- `sudo apt-get install -y nodejs`

This will install the latest `Node` and the latest `npm` as well.

Comment: @AbrarJahin The hold list did not return anything. You are removing the wrong packages. Can you run `sudo apt-get update` and then run the two installation commands I have given above?

Comment: Please have a look in there

Comment: `sudo apt-mark showhold` and `sudo apt-mark unhold <package>`. Can you try this?

Comment: So, your answers are not working, can u please suggest a different approach, please?